# How can I stop and start view.onFrame

Tags: paperjs

I'm pretty new to paperjs. My animation is working for this I use the following javascript:

```
view.onFrame = function () {
    drawYellowBlock();
}
```

The function `drawYellowBlock` draws a yellow block but this animated. When the animation is done I want to stop view.onFrame because I have the feeling it is unnecessary to keep it running while nothing is happening any more. Then when a button is clicked I should be able to activate the onFrame again.

Is this possible and necessary?

*So I want my draw function to be something like this:*

```
var scale = 0;

function drawYellowBlock() {
    scale = scale + 0.1

    //animate block
    if(scale < = 1){
       //make block grow
    }
    else{
       //stop onFrame
    }

$('button').click(function(){
    scale = 0;
    //start onFrame and Animation
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
function draw () {
   drawYellowBlock();
   view.onFrame = undefined
}
view.onFrame = draw

function onclickHandler(){ 
   view.onFrame = draw
}
```

just remove the function reference from the onFrame handler once its done and append the function back once the button is clicked

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set up a flag used in `onFrame` method to check if you should animate or not.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.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) demonstrating the solution.

```
// Draw the item with a small initial scale.
var item = new Path.Rectangle({
    from: view.center - 100,
    to: view.center + 100,
    fillColor: 'orange',
    applyMatrix: false
});
item.scaling = 0.1;

// Draw instructions.
new PointText({
    content: 'Press space to start animation',
    point: view.center + [0, -80],
    justification: 'center'
});

// Create a flag that we will use to know wether we should animate or not.
var animating = false;

// On space key pressed...
function onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.key === 'space') {
        // ...start animation.
        animating = true;
    }
}

// On frame...
function onFrame() {
    // ...if animation has started...
    if (animating) {
        // ...scale up the item.
        item.scaling += 0.05;
        // When item is totally scaled up...
        if (item.scaling.x >= 1) {
            // ...stop animation.
            animating = false;
        }
    }
}
```